# LinkedList give me the wrong output?

Tags: java, linked-list, output, tostring

I am struggeling at my LinkedList. The Output is wrong.
I get this:`

```
[January 2016, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
```

What I want is this:

```
January 2016 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31`
```

Thats my Declaration and initializatian of the variable I need;

```
private final String[] monthname = {null, "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
            "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

    private LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> planlist = new LinkedList<>();
    private int year = 2017; // Default year
```

Here is my Method to build a Month paper. In this method I add to a LinkedList values and give it back to another LinkedList as type.

```
public LinkedList<String> buildMonth(int month) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    LinkedList<String> monthList= new LinkedList<>();
    String header= this.monthname[month] + " " + this.year;
    monatListe.add(header);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        String converterInt = String.valueOf(i);
        monthList.add(converterInt.toString());

    }
    return monthList;
}
```

At the end I want to show you how I output my LinkedList. I try it with iterator but it dont work so I decided this way.

```
    public String getYearplan(int from, int until) {
        if (von <= bis) {
            for (int i = von; i <= bis; i++) {
                this.planlist.add(buildMonth(i));
                System.out.println(buildMonth(i));
            }
        }
return null;
}
```

I hope you can I help I try to figure out but nothing worked. I try with toString() and without toString but I have no idea.

Best Regards

Michael Dev

Answer (score 1):

You're doing

```
System.out.println(buildMonth(i));
```

`buildMonth()` returns a `LinkedList<String>`.  `println` needs a String to print, so it calls `LinkedList`'s `toString()`.  The output you see is what `toString()` generated, what the programmers of `LinkedList` thought might be most useful to other programmers trying to use `LinkedList`s.

Since you don't like what the `LinkedList` developers provided for you, you'll just have to take matters into your own hands and program the output the way you want it to look.  Something like this, perhaps:

```
LinkedList<String> month = buildMonth(i);
for (String s : month) {
    System.out.println(s + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

So you just want a string with the values separated by space, then do this:

```
String.join(" ", planlist);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, here should be ...?

```
public String getYearplan(int from, int until) {
    if (from <= until) {
        for (int i = from; i <= until; i++) {
            List list = buildMonth(i);
            this.planlist.add(list);
            System.out.println(list);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```